# How to fix Set.of() cannot find symbol: method of(String,String)?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, set

I'm trying to use `Set.of()` to create a set of string. Here is my import and code. I don't know why it always reports cannot find symbol:

```
import java.util.Set;
Set<String> existedFieldsValueList = Set.of("field1", "field2");
```

Here is the error log

```
[javac]     Set<String> existedFieldsValueList = Set.of("field1", "field2");
[javac]                                             ^
[javac]   symbol:   method of(String,String)
[javac]   location: interface Set
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: When a method or class seems to be missing, look at the *latest* version of Java for its Javadoc. That Javadoc has a “Since" field showing the version of Java when that feature was added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method was introduced in JDK 9. From the error message, it looks like you're using an older JDK. Upgrade to a newer one and you should be fine.